# How do I get access to a standard dictionary in Android?

Tags: android, dictionary, keyboard

I've developed a software keyboard for Android. I want to use for suggestion the dictionary that uses the standard Android keyboard. How can I access from my application to this dictionary?

Comment: Hello, did you found any solution to access standard dictionary used in android?